# How to add string or message in a deprecated function

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am having a function say void `foo()`. I am deprecating is as 
old func:-

```
void foo()__attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

new func:-

```
void FOO();
```

Now I want to add a message along with this in old function that "the new function used is `FOO`" which can be seen along with the warning message which we will get after compiling the code.

How to do this.

Comment: add `-Wall` to the compiler command?

Comment: Please accept one of the answers (the tick below the vote counter) if you're satisfied with it. Otherwise update the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `[[deprecated(msg)]]` attribute, which is a standard way to do that as well (since C++14).

```
[[deprecated("do not use")]]
void f()
{}

int main(){

f();
}
```

output of `clang++`:

```
warning: 'f' is deprecated: do not use [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
f();
^
note: 'f' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
void f()
     ^
1 warning generated.
```

output of `g++`:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
warning: ‘void f()’ is deprecated (declared at test.cpp:2): do not use [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 f();
 ^
warning: ‘void f()’ is deprecated (declared at test.cpp:2): do not use [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 f();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the message inside the attribute itself (since GCC 4.5)

```
void __attribute__ ((deprecated("the new function used is FOO"))) foo();
```

Alternatively you can use the new syntax (C++14)

```
[[deprecated("the new function used is FOO")]]
void foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C++14, you can use this syntax:

```
[[deprecated("Replaced by FOO, which has extra goodness")]]
void foo();
```

Note that you can only use a string literal for the message.